# Varying Intensity of Texture Map Over Single Mesh

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I am trying to make the texturing more consistent on a lightsaber.

*What I have -- I've highlighted important areas of contrast:*

[image]

My issue is that the map (used to generate bump as well as coloration) produces far more bumps/dirt on the front half of the lightsaber (before the center switch/grip) as opposed to the back half. I have tried matching up the two parts' UV projections but to no avail.

*My node setup:*

[image]

On the .blend, I have two RenderLayers -- one for the lightsaber and one for the wood floor (this is because I use *Microdisplacements* and *Adaptive Subdivision Surface* on the wooden floor, both of which are tough on my GPU's memory). I have four UV maps for the lightsaber (for organizational purposes -- three are added together in my *UVTexCoords* node). I have an HDRI background and several textures (all packed save the HDRI, but you can download it from [Textures.com](https://www.textures.com/download/hdrpanoramas0001/127776?q=panorama), if you wish). Here it is:

[image]

Comment: I'm not in a position to check your file currently, but could it be the scale (or rotation) on those meshes is different? I thought it could be a problem with your Mapping node, but all three axes have the same value, so that seems to be in order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vertex paint and input the result with an attribute node:

here is a detailed mesh
[image: here is a detailed mesh]

Here is the vertex paint

[image]

Here is the node setup
[image: Here is the node setup]

and here is the result

[image]

Comment: This does not answer what I asked in my question. I asked about fixing an existing issue related to image textures -- nothing with vertex paint.

Comment: I missunderstood your question because i didnt look at your blend file I think your atempt to fix the problem is the right onebecause the problem is related to UV mapping